# Windows 10 - start up and shut down on power

Tags: windows, startup, shutdown

I'm using a Windows 10 tablets for a museum's interactive exhibit.
Each tablet is embedded in a table and always connected to the power supply.
I'd like to:
- shut down Windows when AC power goes off (i.e. the device start feeding from battery). Is there an event I can use in the task scheduler? I couldn't find it.
- start up when AC comes alive.
Any suggestion appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think there is way to start or stop the windows by AC power. However, you can realize what you want by [remote control](https://tommynation.com/shut-windows-10-remote-desktop-rdp/).

Comment: Unfortunately the tablets won't be connected to a wifi. I would have been quite simple to shoot down them in that case :(

Answer (score 0):

This might be a problem better suited for a hardware logic gate controller.  for example i picture something like:

```
laptop running code to monitor when (logic happens) >
send a signal to a remotely controllable power source >
```

like this example product:

https://3gstore.com/product/4186_single_outlet_remote_power_switch.html